# Add columns in farpoint spread dynamically in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

i have spread named sprBase in that i wanna add columns based upon the date filters ,
if one day selected then i need to add one column with that date name , if i select 4 dates then 4 columns should be added with those date names dynamically.

Comment: Have you done some research (google and youtube) if yes , I would recommend you to read this [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please share the code that you had already tried!